# [PFCommandResult boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I oddly get this error message when I run my new project.

I do think it has something to do with PFAnalytics. Because if I comment out PFAnalytics, it will silence the error.

It won't crash the app.

Here is the code:

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions,
    block: {(succeeded:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void in
      if error == nil{
        println("PFAnalytics initiated successfully!")
      }
    })
```

How do I resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: This is a known issue and should be fixed in the next SDK release https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1640577069503156/

Comment: I see, but since I couldn't find it on Stackoverflow. I wish to keep this so the following visitors can view your message

Comment: Quick update: This was supposed to be fixed in the 1.6.2 iOS release but it seems people are still have the problem, including myself.